# Podman Compose Golang Docker Image is not connecting to Postgres Docker Image

Tags: postgresql, go, podman, podman-compose

I'm new to `podman` and trying to use `podman-compose` to build multiple docker images from the `docker-compose.yml` file. I'm unable to get my `authentication-service` golang app docker image connected to the Postgres docker image. I tried checking [this question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58Vlx.png) but wasn't of much help. I'm unable to understand why is there no host

```
failed to connect to `host=postgres user=postgres database=users`: hostname resolving error (lookup postgres on 10.89.0.1:53: no such host)
```

Podman commands used:

`podman-compose up -d`

`podman ps`

`podman logs container-id`

Podman logs:

[image: podman terminal logs]

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'

services:

  broker-service:
    build:
      context: ./../broker-service
      dockerfile: ./../broker-service/broker-service.dockerfile
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1

  authentication-service:
    build:
      context: ./../authentication-service
      dockerfile: ./../authentication-service/authentication-service.dockerfile
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8081:80"
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1
    environment:
      DSN: "host=postgres port=5432 user=postgres password=password dbname=users sslmode=disable timezone=UTC connect_timeout=5"

  postgres:
    image: 'postgres:14.2'
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    restart: always
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      POSTGRES_DB: users
    volumes:
      - ./db-data/postgres/:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
```

`main.go`:

```
package main

import (
    "authentication-service/data"
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "time"

    _ "github.com/jackc/pgconn"
    _ "github.com/jackc/pgx/v4"
    _ "github.com/jackc/pgx/v4/stdlib"
)

const webPort = "80"

var counts int64

type Config struct {
    DB     *sql.DB
    Models data.Models
}

func main() {
    log.Println("Starting authentication server")

    // connect to DB
    conn := connectToDB()
    if conn == nil {
        log.Panic("Can't connect to Postgres!")
    }

    // setup config
    app := Config{
        DB:     conn,
        Models: data.New(conn),
    }

    // define http server
    srv := &http.Server{
        Addr:    fmt.Sprintf(":%s", webPort),
        Handler: app.routes(),
    }

    // start the server
    err := srv.ListenAndServe()
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }
}

// function to open the database
func openDB(dsn string) (*sql.DB, error) {
    db, err := sql.Open("pgx", dsn)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("open db pgx error: %s", err)
        return nil, err
    }

    err = db.Ping()
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("db ping error: %s", err)
        return nil, err
    }

    return db, nil
}

// function to connect to the database
func connectToDB() *sql.DB {
    dsn := os.Getenv("DSN")

    for {
        connection, err := openDB(dsn)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("Postgres not yet ready...")
            counts++
        } else {
            log.Println("Connected to Postgres!")
            return connection
        }

        if counts > 10 {
            log.Println(err)
            return nil
        }

        log.Println("Backing off for 2 seconds...")
        time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
        continue
    }
}
```

Comment: So, the obvious question is - do you have DNS configured and working on the podman network you are using?

Comment: @RichardHuxton Could you please help me how to check if it's enabled or configured? I tried to check the below doc but couldn't wrap my head around it

https://docs.podman.io/en/latest/markdown/podman-network-create.1.html